# Retrieve object with nativeQuery in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want retrieve an object with native query in Symfony 2

my code is:

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping($this->getEntityManager());
        $rsm->addEntityResult('SNUserBundle:User', 'u');
        $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'nickname', 'nickname');

        $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery('SELECT u.nickname FROM u WHERE u.nickname = ?', $rsm);
        $query->setParameter(1, 'barno7');


        $users = $query->getResult();
```

I have this error

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT u.nickname FROM u WHERE u.nickname = ?' with params ["barno7"]:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sn.u' doesn't exist
```

my table name sn_user and in my entity SNUserBundle:User have this annotation

```
 * @ORM\Table(name="sn_user")
```

i try also

```
$query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery('SELECT u.nickname FROM user WHERE u.nickname = ?', $rsm);
```

and my error is

```
An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT u.nickname FROM users WHERE u.nickname = ?' with params ["barno7"]:

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'sn.user' doesn't exist
```

my real table is sn_user

Comment: Shouldn't the query be something like `SELECT u.nickname FROM sn_user u WHERE u.nickname = ?` You need to alias the table properly. I don't know if that is the main issue, but that appears to be one.

Comment: @keyboardSmasher no but thanks, I forgot

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing up SQL and DQL, or the functions that use each.  It looks like you want to use DQL to query, which will return an object.  In that case, you don't use the `createNativeQuery` method.  This method if for SQL.

See the [Symfony docs on DQL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql) for an example of how to query with DQL.  Here is the example snippet from the docs:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
    FROM AcmeStoreBundle:Product p
    WHERE p.price > :price
    ORDER BY p.price ASC'
)->setParameter('price', '19.99');

$products = $query->getResult();
```

follow this syntax, and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve like this

```
$rsm = new ResultSetMapping;
    $rsm->addEntityResult('SNUserBundle:User', 'u');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'id', 'id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('u', 'n', 'nickname');

    $query = $this->getEntityManager()->createNativeQuery('
    SELECT u.id ,u.nickname as n FROM sn_user u WHERE u.nickname LIKE = ?', $rsm);
    $query->setParameter(1, 'barno7');       

    $users = $query->execute();
    return $users;
```